# Grouping variables based on location, year and person name

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I would like to create an aggregate of columns

```
A<- c("xyz", "xyz", "xy", "xx","xx", "y")
year<- c(2009,2010,2009,2009,2010,2009)
location<- c('london', 'london', 'paris', 'newyork','mumbai','sydney')
df<- data.frame(A, year, location)
```

I would like to create a variable called 'yearsofexperience'which will summarize the total numbers of years spent by one person in a given location.

```
   A     year         location  yearsofexperience
   xyz  2009          london     2
   xyz  2010          london     2
   xy   2009          paris      1
   xx   2009          newyork    1
   xx   2010          mumbai     1
   y    2009          sydeny     1
```

Can someone help?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(A, location) %>% mutate(yearsofexperience = n())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `n_distinct()` to count the unique years for each combination of person and location. This should work for you:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(A, location) %>% mutate(yoe = n_distinct(year))

# Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
# Groups: A, location [5]

#       A  year location   yoe
#  <fctr> <dbl>   <fctr> <int>
#1    xyz  2009   london     2
#2    xyz  2010   london     2
#3     xy  2009    paris     1
#4     xx  2009  newyork     1
#5     xx  2010   mumbai     1
#6      y  2009   sydney     1
```

You can also use `data.table` syntax and the corresponding function is `uniqueN()`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, yoe := uniqueN(year), .(A, location)]
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is interested here is a (arguably neater) solution using `data.table` that should be much faster on a big dataset.

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, yearsofexperience := .N, by = .(A, location)]
df
     A year location yearsofexperience
1: xyz 2009   london                 2
2: xyz 2010   london                 2
3:  xy 2009    paris                 1
4:  xx 2009  newyork                 1
5:  xx 2010   mumbai                 1
6:   y 2009   sydney                 1
```

Answer (score 3):

using `dplyr` you can use `group_by` and `mutate` to get the output you listed in your question

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(A, location) %>% 
  mutate(yearsofexperience = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

If you want to collapse the entries for a given `A` & `location` you can use `summarise` in place of the mutate statement.  This will drop the `year` variable.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(A, location) %>% 
  summarise(yearsofexperience = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: awesome! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ave` from `base R`

```
df$yearsofexperience <- with(df, ave(year, location, A, FUN = length))
df
#     A year location yearsofexperience
#1 xyz 2009   london                 2
#2 xyz 2010   london                 2
#3  xy 2009    paris                 1
#4  xx 2009  newyork                 1
#5  xx 2010   mumbai                 1
#6   y 2009   sydney                 1
```

If this is based on the `length` of `unique` elements

```
df$yearsofexperience <- with(df, ave(year, location, A, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))))
```